# HTML tag <center> </center>

Tags: html, attributes, element

I just started to learn HTML.

I couldn't find any information about the element `<center></center>`

Some website also notify this tag is not supported in HTML5 is this same as HTML?

Comment: What's the difference between HTML and HTML5, is this upgraded version of HTML?

Comment: @Rinseo - While things are not generally characterized this way. formally "HTML5" refers to the *specification*. I.e., It is the fifth major edition of the specification of the HyperText Markup Language (HTML).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<center>` tag was used to center a text. But, unfortunately, it's not supported in HTML5.
Use the `text-align: center;` propriety in CSS. It's more advanced than `<center>`.
Here are different values for `text-align: center;`:

- `left` – The default value. Content aligns along the left side.
- `right` – Content aligns along the right side.
- `center` – Content centers between the left and right edges. White
  space on the left and right sides of each line should be equal.
- `justify` – Content spaces out such that as many blocks fit onto one
  line as possible and the first word on that line is along the left
  edge and the last word is along the right edge.
- `inherit` – The value will be whatever the parent element’s is.

And here is an example (center a text in a paragraph):

```
p {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Simple, right?

Answer (score 1):

It is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Use CSS instead. Like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm starting off in HTML on website "codepen.io"
however I found out how to properly use this as start and end.

Comment: @Rinseo - "Obsolete" means that you **shouldn't** use it. There is no way to "properly" use the element, although it has an effect if you *improperly* use it.

Answer (score 1):

`<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5, but you can use CSS instead:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">Some text</p>
```